# Getting columns of multiple SQL tables in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get all the metadata values related to a document in a single query, be it with null in some columns.

Example:

```
DOCUMENT table     ATTRIBUTE_1 values    ATTRIBUTE_2 values

Id | Name          DocId | Value         DocId | Value
-----------        ---------------       ---------------
1  | Doc1          1     | Val1          1     | ValA
2  | Doc2          1     | Val2          1     | ValB
                                         1     | ValC
```

For Doc1, I want the query to return the values for each attribute ordered alphabetically:

```
Attr1     | Attr2
--------------------
Val1      | ValA
Val2      | ValB
NULL      | ValC
```

I tried a very naive query:

```
SELECT a1.Value, a2.Value FROM ATTRIBUTE_1 a1, ATTRIBUTE_2 a2, DOCUMENT d 
WHERE d.Id = a1.DocId AND d.Id = a2.DocId AND d.Id = 1
```

I tried doing inner joins, I tried googling but couldn't find terms which weren't about merging multiple columns in a single one.

The database used is Oracle.

How can I achieve this goal?

Thank you

Comment: How are the "attributes" ordered? In other words, why is the third row in you expected results `NULL | ValC`?

Comment: What connection is there between `Val1` and `Val2` so that they must appear side-by-side? (the same goes for all pairs in the result)

Comment: @Colin'tHart I added some details about what I tried. The sorting should be alphabetical then `NULL`.
@geomagas Do you mean `Val1` and `ValA`? If yes, the columns only need to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: I hope `Val1, Val2, ...` are just examples, because `Val10` will sort before `Val9`.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Yes these are just silly examples because I don't have the right to send the real values outside of my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
with a1 as (
   select
     row_number() over (partition by DocId order by Value) as r,
     DocId,
     value
   from
     ATTRIBUTE_1
), a2 as (
   select
     row_number() over (partition by DocId order by Value) as r,
     DocId,
     value
   from
     ATTRIBUTE_2
)
select a1.Value as Attr1, a2.Value as Attr2
from a1 full outer join a2 using (DocId, r) join DOCUMENT on (DocId = Id);
```

See this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3526/3/0